# Read CSV and assign it to service SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend

I recently started exploring backend and SpringBoot and came across a big problem in my small project. I wanted to create a RestController in which I have a service that reads a singular .csv file and creates a List of objects (Id and conversionRate). However, I can't assign List's values to service, since I'm not creating a service object. Should I create a database and pull values and create objects from there?

```
@Service
public class CurrencyService {
    private List<Currency> currencies = CSVReader.readCSVFile(); //Doesn't work since readCSVFile() is static
}
```

Comment: Where does the CSV come from? Is it sent to your REST service? Or do you want to have some sort of static initialization, where the CSV is read into memory on application startup?

Comment: You could declare currencies as static.

Comment: I would prefer static initialization, however I am not sure if REST Controller would be able to mutate the list with endpoints. @slauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to read the CSV file at startup and keep it in memory, you can use `@PostConstruct` annotation to do just that:

```java
@Service
public class CurrencyService {
    private List<Currency> currencies;

    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        currencies = CSVReader.readCSVFile();
    }
}
```

Reference documentation:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy#postConstruct